# How do I parse this HTML code with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have the following HTML:

```
<h3><strong>Adresse:</strong></h3>
    <p>
Hochschule Darmstadt<br>
TechnologieTransferCentrum<br>
D19, Raum 221, 222<br>
Schöfferstraße 10<br>
<b>64295 Darmstadt</b><p>
<h3>Kommunikationsdaten: </h3> 
<p>
```

But the `<p>` and `<br>` tags are not closed.

How do I extract the address information:

```
Hochschule Darmstadt
TechnologieTransferCentrum
D19, Raum 221, 222
Schöfferstraße 10
64295 Darmstadt
```

Comment: what are you asking exactly, where should the closing tags go?

Comment: like when you parse html.css('h1'),it gets the information between<h1></h1>,but these codes do not have closing tags, how to get the information

Comment: How do you plan to identify the appropriate `<h3>`? Is it safe to assume it is the only one that is in `<strong>` or do you need to identify by its name ("Adresse")?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from this basis:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<h3><strong>Adresse:</strong></h3>
    <p>
Hochschule Darmstadt<br>
TechnologieTransferCentrum<br>
D19, Raum 221, 222<br>
Schöfferstraße 10<br>
<b>64295 Darmstadt</b><p>
<h3>Kommunikationsdaten: </h3> 
<p>
EOT

puts doc.errors
puts doc.to_html
```

I get this when I run the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<h3><strong>Adresse:</strong></h3>
    <p>
Hochschule Darmstadt<br>
TechnologieTransferCentrum<br>
D19, Raum 221, 222<br>
Schöfferstraße 10<br><b>64295 Darmstadt</b></p>
<p>
</p>
<h3>Kommunikationsdaten: </h3>
<p></p>
</body></html>
```

Notice that Nokogiri has added the `<html>` and `<body>` tags. Also, it has closed the `<p>` tags, adding `</p>`. We can tell it to parse the HTML as a fragment, and not add the headers using instead:

```
Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse
```

Which generates:

```
<h3><strong>Adresse:</strong></h3>
    <p>
Hochschule Darmstadt<br>
TechnologieTransferCentrum<br>
D19, Raum 221, 222<br>
Schöfferstraße 10<br><b>64295 Darmstadt</b></p><p>
</p><h3>Kommunikationsdaten: </h3>
<p></p>
```

There's still fixup on the HTML happening, but it's the basic HTML passed in. Either way, the resulting HTML is technically correct.

On to finding the text in question: If there is only one `<p>` tag, or it's the first one:

```
doc.at('p').text
=> "\nHochschule Darmstadt\nTechnologieTransferCentrum\nD19, Raum 221, 222\nSchöfferstraße 1064295 Darmstadt"
```

Or:

```
doc.at('h3').next_sibling.next_sibling.text
=> "\nHochschule Darmstadt\nTechnologieTransferCentrum\nD19, Raum 221, 222\nSchöfferstraße 1064295 Darmstadt"
```

Two `next_sibling` methods are needed. The first finds the text node immediately following the end of the `<h3>` node:

```
doc.at('h3').next_sibling
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fef59dedfb8 "\n    ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have parsed the document in `doc`, this:

```
puts doc.at('//h3[contains(strong, "Adresse:")]/following-sibling::p').text
```

will give you the following output:

```
Hochschule Darmstadt
TechnologieTransferCentrum
D19, Raum 221, 222
Schöfferstraße 10
64295 Darmstadt
```